# Remove the duplicate data through Row Number

Tags: sql

Please can someone help as I have been trying the row number but I am getting all the rows as 1.

Please see the below sample data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj73I.png)

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DepositorOrderNumber,(CAST(DWH_INSERT_DATE AS datetime)), LineSequenceNumber 
                           ORDER BY DepositorOrderNumber,(CAST(DWH_INSERT_DATE AS datetime)), LineSequenceNumber ASC) AS Row_Num,
        DepositorOrderNumber, LineSequenceNumber, 
        (CAST(DWH_INSERT_DATE AS datetime)) AS InsertDate
    FROM 
        [Jda].[DM_Fact_940_OrderLineItem]
    WHERE
        Depot_Slicer_Name = 'Depot DC' 
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE ROW_Num = 1 AND DepositorOrderNumber = '557083'
```

Comment: You partition by the same columns as you order by. Also why do you cast `DWH_INSERT_DATE` to a `datetime`? Isn't it already? Why not?

Comment: And please tag your dbms, and don't use (link to) pictures for data/code/error messages. Use (formatted) text for all

Comment: What should the desired output look like?

Answer (score -1):

Try change where with group this will return 1 value

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DepositorOrderNumber,(CAST(DWH_INSERT_DATE AS datetime)), LineSequenceNumber 
                           ORDER BY DepositorOrderNumber,(CAST(DWH_INSERT_DATE AS datetime)), LineSequenceNumber ASC) AS Row_Num,
        DepositorOrderNumber, LineSequenceNumber, 
        (CAST(DWH_INSERT_DATE AS datetime)) AS InsertDate
    FROM 
        [Jda].[DM_Fact_940_OrderLineItem]
    WHERE
        Depot_Slicer_Name = 'Depot DC' 
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
GROUP BY DepositorOrderNumber
```

Comment: `[]` suggest sql server, this query would give an error (also on most other systems). Also, what is the logic behind your solution?